# Writing compressed netCDF4 files with raster

Tags: r, raster, gdal, rgdal

I want to write compressed netCDF4 files using the `raster` package.
`ncdf4` and `rgdal` are installed correctly.

The following, however, fails to return a netCDF4 compressed file:

```
library(raster)
r <- raster() <- runif(86400)
r[] <- <- runif(86400)
writeRaster(r, "test.nc", options=c("COMPRESS=DEFLATE", "FORMAT=NC4"))
```

In fact it just returns a standard netCDF file:

```
bash $ > cdo sinfo test.nc 
   File format : netCDF
```

Not only uncompressed, but not even netCDF4.

According to the GDAL documentation, these options should work (see [here](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_netcdf.html), under "Creation options").
According to the raster manual, under `writeRaster`:

> options: Character. File format specific GDAL options. E.g., when
>   writing a geotiff file you can use: options=c("COMPRESS=NONE",
>   "TFW=YES")

What could be wrong?

Comment: If you can, avoid the use `writeRaster` to write NetCDF and prefer the functions from the `ncdf4` package. It will allow you to use compression (in function `ncvar_def`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ncdf files are not written via GDAL because the rgdal package (at least the binary version on windows) does not come with the ncdf driver. Instead, writeRaster uses package `ncdf` or (preferably) `ncdf4`, so you would have to use arguments provided by the ncdf4 package (in the `ncvar_def` function). That is, you would do e.g., `compression=7`, which would automatically turn the file into ncdf4 format. However, the current version of `raster` would ignore these arguments. I have fixed that in the development version on R-Forge (version 2.4-7), such that you can do:

```
writeRaster(r, "test.nc", datatype='INT2S', force_v4=TRUE, compression=7)
```

(The `force_v4` argument is passed to `nc_create`).

Comment: thanks. I think that that should be specified in the manual: I knew that `raster` used `ncdf4` but in the `writeRaster` manual entry only GDAL is mentioned in `options`. I will try the dev version. Thanks again for the reply and for the **excellent** package.